# How to pull Data Extension Details used in previous sends from _Job Data View

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, query, dataextensions, data-views

I have a recurring automation that runs daily that sends an e-mail to a list which is overwritten daily in the first step of the program via a list import.

I need to generate a DE that shows every e-mail address this particular automation was sent to plus the attributes associated with each e-mail address. So if johndoe@gmail.com received the e-mail, I want it to return back his e-mail address, and any other attributes present (such as First Name, Order ID, Promo Code, etc.) in the target DE.

Is this possible to do writing a query that looks at the _Job Data View? Or should I use a different Data View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this automation uses a specific email id , email name or user-initiated send, you can retrieve the **jobId(s**) from the **_jobs** system data view.  Your query would then need to join the **_sent** system date view in order to retrieve the recipient's email address for a particular job.

Knowing the sattribute values at the time-of-send is a little tricker.  If the data were written to the SendLog, then it could be retrieved via a query by referencing the **jobId(s)**.

You can reference the online documentation for a complete list of fields available in these system data views.

reference:  http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/